# trying to make a simpler insertion at end of linked list program.Help needed with minor issues

Tags: c++, list, insertion

I have managed to create a simple insertion at beginnning of linked list program but now i am struggling with insertion at end of linked list.

The program seems to be able to take values from user but the output list is not coming correct.Could you help me out?

If possible keep along the lines of my program as i am beginner and won't be able to understand a completely different method.

Logic i used-
If list is empty then insert value at beginning else if list is not empty then travel along the list till the next value being pointed at is NULL and then enter the new value in place of NULL.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
        int data;
        node *next;
};
node *start=NULL;
void insertend(int x)
{
   node* temp=new node;
   if(start==NULL)
        temp->data=x;
   else
    {
            while(temp!=NULL)
            {
                    temp=temp->next;
            }
            temp->next=x;
    }
}
void display()
{
        node* disp=new node;
        while(disp!=NULL)
        {
                cout<<disp->data<<endl;
        disp=disp->next;
        }
}
int main()
{
        int x;
        char ch;
        do
        {
                cout<<"Enter data";cin>>x;
                cout<<endl;
                insertend(x);
                cout<<"Do you want to continue?(y/n)";cin>>ch;
        cout<<endl;
        }while(ch=='y');
cout<<"Your list:"<<endl;
display();

}
```

Comment: Can you point to the exact place in `insertend()` which will set `start` to the very first element in the list. Also, can you point to the exact place in your program that will initialize `data` if the list is not empty to start with. Once you are able to answer those question, you should know all that needs to be known in order to fix your code. While you're trying to figure this out, keep in mind rule #1 of computer programming: a computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do. The "logic you used" does not match what the code actually does.

Comment: Rule #2 of computer programming: don't ignore warning messages from your compiler. Your compiler issues a warning message because there's a reason for that, and not because it wants to verify that the compiler knows how to show a message. Just because the compiler still ended up compiling the program doesn't mean that the program was correct. That warning message from your compiler is there for a reason.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a site to solve student home work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry point to your list is the variable `start`. But you never set it. Take for example the first item a user inputs. You will call `insertend()`, it will check that `start == NULL`, but then it never sets `start`. You must set `start = temp` or something similar. You have the same problem in the `else` section -- you loop through the nodes starting with `temp`, but you should be starting with `start`. And again in the function `display()`, you create a pointer to a node and start looping from it, but it will have no data -- you should use `start` as the starting point of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node{
int data;
node* next;
};  

node *first = NULL, *last = NULL;

void insert(int x){
    if(first == NULL){
        first = new node;
        first->data = x;
        first->next = NULL;
    }else if(last == NULL){
        last = new node;
        last->data = x;
        first->next = last;
        last->next = NULL;
    }else{
        node *n = new node;
        n->data = x;
        n->next = NULL;
        last->next = n;
        last = n;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am keeping track of first and last node in the list. Insert function checks if there is anything in the list with `if(first == NULL)`part. If there isn't it creates the first node. Similar thing happens with the else if. Finally in the else block we create a new node with data x. Then point the node stored in variable last to our new node and set last to be that node. 
Here is the display function:

```
void display()
{
    node *disp =first;

    while(disp->next != NULL){
        cout << disp->data << " ";
        disp = disp->next;
    }

    cout << disp->data;
}
```

I also recommend that you do a cleanup after your program is finished running since you are creating new nodes.

```
void cleanup(node* n)
{
    if(n->next == NULL)return delete n;
    cleanup(n->next);
    delete n;
}
```

and then at the end of main call `cleanup(first)`

Hope this makes sense :) Have a nice day!